# Required field is missing ChartSummaries

Tags: deployment

[image]

I am getting above error when I was trying to deploy reports with eclipse.

And, when i tired with chagneset , it didn't get uploaded to other org and have got an email from Salesforce to raise a case .

The following outbound change set upload failed due to a system error:

Change set: R2 Reports and Dashboard (04t17000000D43v)
Organization: PRMSB1 (Partial Data Sandbox) (00D170000008mU5)
User: Ankit Khandelwal (00517000000DlVp)
Error Number: 1503221106-19826 (637934141)

Please try to upload your change set again. If it does not succeed, contact Customer Support and provide the error number listed above.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error when moving reports in one folder to another (after cutting and pasting them to the right folder and saving them to the workspace on my computer and refreshing the Eclipse project).  I was able to click Next and the reports moved into the correct report folder.

I forgot to add that I used "Deploy to Server" instead of "Save to Server" but I used these instructions:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000guQCAAY

Comment: In case the link becomes invalid in the future it might be a good idea to paste the instructions directly into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today
I resolved it by opening the report xml in eclipse, and adding the following tag:

```
<chartSummaries>
            <axisBinding>y</axisBinding>
            <column>RowCount</column>
</chartSummaries>
```

between the backgroundFadeDir and chartType tags

it seems this is required when the report's chart is displayed on a dashboard